# Can't call handler without any activity???

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, handler, delay

I want my broadcast receiver to open an activity 4 seconds after an incoming call is catched. To make the delay, I'm using the Handler class, but something pretty strange happens. Firstly, see my code:

```
package com.example.nrsearch;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;

public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
public CallReceiver() {
}

public Context context;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i("CallReceiverBroadcast", "onReceive() is called.");
    this.context = context;
    TelephonyManager teleMgr = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    PhoneStateListener psl = new PhoneStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            Log.i("CallReceiverBroadcast", "onCallStateChanged() is called.");
            switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                Log.i("CallReceiverBroadcast", "Incoming call caught. Caller's number is " + incomingNumber + ".");
                if (!checkContactExistance(incomingNumber)) {
                    Handler handler = new Handler() {
                        @Override
                        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                            if (msg.what == 1) {
                                Log.i("CallReceiverBroadcast", "Handler works!");
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    startNumberDisplayActivity(incomingNumber);
                    Message message = Message.obtain(handler, 1);
                    handler.sendMessageDelayed(message, 1*4000);
                }
            }
            Log.i("CallReceiverBroadcast", "onCallStateChanged() is finished.");
        }
    };
    teleMgr.listen(psl, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    teleMgr.listen(psl, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
    Log.i("CallReceiverBroadcast", "onReceive() is finished.");
}

public void startNumberDisplayActivity(String incomingNumber) {
    Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    i.putExtra("incomingNumber", incomingNumber);
    context.startActivity(i);
}

public boolean checkContactExistance(String number) {
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(number));
    ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
    Cursor contactLookup = contentResolver.query(uri, new String[] {ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME}, null, null, null);
    if (contactLookup != null && contactLookup.getCount() > 0) {
        Log.i("CallReceiverBroadcast", "The incoming number exists.");
        contactLookup.close();
        return true;
    } else {
        Log.i("CallReceiverBroadcast", "The incoming number doesn't exist.");
        contactLookup.close();
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

The problem is, now the `startNumberDisplayActivity(incomingNumber);` is outside the handler handleMessage() method, because if I put this line there, then the handler is not working, it is never called. But I need to start this activity from within the handler, because I need it to be delayed. Why the handler isn't working if I start the activity from within it? How to do this correctly? By the way, this Broadcast Receiver is registered in the manifest and is filtering intent android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE. It is called whenever the incoming call comes and it is meant to start the activity.

Comment: Why would you want to start an `Activity` when an incoming phone call is received? That's just going to interfere with the user being able to use their phone normally.

Comment: I know it's kinda annoying but I still need an answer because this behavior is very strange. Now the handler works perfectly, but if I move that line to the handler's handleMessage() method, that method is then never called.

Comment: Maybe I know the answer but I'm not sure if it's right. Maybe the handler is never called because if there is no any acitivity then there is no thread which could manage its message queue? I mean if I don't start an activity before I call that handler,  itcannot be called because there is no thread to manage that call?